# Azure hosted WCF which creates a excel in my c drive

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, azure, dynamics-crm-2011

My function header looks like this when I call it from a plugin.

```
chanl.createTsDetailsXls(@"c:\Users\Public\Documents\TestScheduleDetails.xlsx", (entity.Id).ToString());
```

But when this WCF is hosted in Azure, Azure cant access my C drive, so where should I save this excel file created in my WCF.

Answer (score 0):

If your WCF is host in the **Azure WebApp** that it is not allowed to access the `C:` drive in the Azure.
 But we can access the shared folder `D:\home`, more detail info about WebApp sandbox please refer to [document](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox).
we also can save our files in the [Azure storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-introduction) if it is possible.